# Dell XPS 9380 no audio from TB16 dock headphone or output jack after Firmware 1.8.0

Tags: sound, 19.04, xps

I am running Kubuntu 19.04 on a XPS 13 9380 with the TB16 thunderbolt dock.

Everything was running fine and I could get audio from the dock headphone jack. After upgrading from FW 1.7.0 to 1.8.0, the audio device from the dock still show as USB Audio headphone and USB audio line out. no sound comes out of the devices.

When looking at the advance audio setting, i noticed that the only profile available for USB audio is Default.

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps someone else. (I am not sure why i got down voted ) 
I ended up installing windows 10 in an external HDD and then booting from it. at that point the audio from the dock worked under windows. ( I was trying to rule out a bad Dock ) 
I went back to my ubuntu install and now audio works as expected. I don't have any idea why doing this worked.

Answer (score 0):

Unplugging and pluggin the Dock solved the problem for me, no need to boot in other OS.